# smoothState.js stops other plugins from working ie. wow.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins, jquery-plugins

## Smooth State conflicts with other js plugins

I'm having issues when trying to add [smoothState.js](http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/index.html) to my site it stops [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) from working. No errors are logged in the console.

When using animsition, wow.js works as a callback;

```
var wow = new WOW({
    boxClass:     'wow',      // animated element css class (default is wow)
    animateClass: 'animated', // animation css class (default is animated)
    offset:       0,          // distance to the element when triggering the animation (default is 0)
    mobile:       true,       // trigger animations on mobile devices (default is true)
    live:         true,       // act on asynchronously loaded content (default is true)
    callback:     function(box) { // jshint ignore:line
      // the callback is fired every time an animation is started
      // the argument that is passed in is the DOM node being animated
    }
});
var wowInit = function() {return wow.init();};

var animsitionInit = function(callback) {
    $('.animsition').animsition({
        inClass: 'zoom-in-sm',
        outClass: 'zoom-out-sm',
        inDuration: 1500,
        outDuration: 800,
        linkElement: '.animsition-link',
        loading: true,
        loadingParentElement: 'body', //animsition wrapper element
        loadingClass: 'animsition-loading',
        unSupportCss: ['animation-duration',
            '-webkit-animation-duration',
            '-o-animation-duration'
        ],
        overlay: false,
        overlayClass: 'animsition-overlay-slide',
        overlayParentElement: 'body'
    });
    return callback;
};
animsitionInit(wowInit());
```

Comment: I found with smoothstate that setting in wow "live: true"  to "live:false" - seemed to yield better results - and I needed to run it like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38215965/1729791